# How to diplay a web page as alert

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

when i click a button in asp.net gridview it will execute row command,there i have to write the code to open a specific page... how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer here : [How to open a page in a new tab in the rowcommand event of gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798264/how-to-open-a-page-in-a-new-tab-in-the-rowcommand-event-of-gridview)

```
String js = "window.open('Signature.aspx', '_blank');";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Open Signature.aspx", js, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're looking for javascript's `window.open()`. Here is an example:

```
// from W3Schools
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.focus();
```

If you wish to read more about it, try [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), there is most of information you'll want to know.

*Please keep in mind that those additional popup windows drastically decrease user experience, especially on web applications, so you might want to find an alternative, if possible.*

Answer (score 0):

instead to use an alert box i recommend to use a popup.

take a look to this [link - LIVE EXAMPLE AND REFERENCE TO THIS CODE BELOW](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: {
effect: "blind",
duration: 1000
},
hide: {
effect: "explode",
duration: 1000
}
});
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <iframe src="ShowDetails.aspx"></iframe> 
</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may programmatically create an iframe and add it to the page. If you position it absolutely it will appear on top of the other content of the page.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="button">click me</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var frame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    var body = document.querySelector("body");
    var width = 300;
    var height = 200;
    frame.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp");
    frame.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -" + (width/2) + "px; margin-top: -" + (height/2) + "px");
    body.appendChild(frame);
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing how this works http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/LkcLX/1/

P.S.
notice that you should set width, height and the url inside the click event handler.

Comment: what happens is, when i click a button in gridview it will execute row command,there i have to write the code to open a specific page... how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with ASP. What I gave is pure javascript. I have no idea what you mean by gridview.