# open new tab using gridview CommandField

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

I Have a Gridview as described below :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TrackingNumber" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="TrackingNumber" HeaderText="TID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TrackingNumber" /> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="NationalCode" HeaderText="AID" SortExpression="NationalCode" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicantFName" HeaderText="AFName" SortExpression="ApplicantFName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicantSex" HeaderText="ASex" SortExpression="ApplicantSex"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="dateOfRegister" dataformatstring="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" HeaderText="RegisterDate" SortExpression="dateOfRegister"/>
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/Admin/images/select.png"  ShowSelectButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and on behind code I wrote this code:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["TID"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
  Response.Redirect("../Recruitment/InitPrint.aspx");
}
```

When user click on command field button, page redirect to `InitPrint.aspx` and my code doing well. but I want `InitPrint.aspx` open up in new tab page that `Session["TID"]` will be read there.
Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check the below code. Hope it will help you

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  Session["TID"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('page.aspx','_blank')", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way, you have to use something like that:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["TID"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open("'../Recruitment/InitPrint.aspx','_blank'");",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the target to blank.

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('../Recruitment/InitPrint.aspx','_blank');</script>");
```

and access session value in that page.

May following link will help you more
[ASP.Net-Response.Redirect-or-Server.Transfer-Open-new-window](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net-Response.Redirect-or-Server.Transfer-Open-new-window.aspx)

[Response.Redirect with target from gridview control event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798264/how-to-open-a-page-in-a-new-tab-in-the-rowcommand-event-of-gridview)